# Create list of combinations

Tags: python, list, combinations

I would like to create a list of numbers with three values and would like to cover every combination from 0 - 3. For example:

```
0, 0, 0
0, 0, 1
...
1, 0, 3
1, 1, 3
```

all the way to `3, 3, 3`.

Is there a better way to do this than using multiple for loops?

Here is the code that I used:

```
for i in range (0, 4):
    for x in range (0, 4):
        for t in range (0, 4):
        assign = [i, x, t]
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

`list(itertools.product(range(4), repeat=3))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product({0, 1, 2, 3}, repeat=3))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 2, 3), (0, 3, 0), (0, 3, 1), (0, 3, 2), (0, 3, 3), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 0), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 3), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 0, 3), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 3, 0), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3), (3, 0, 0), (3, 0, 1), (3, 0, 2), (3, 0, 3), (3, 1, 0), (3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3), (3, 2, 0), (3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2), (3, 2, 3), (3, 3, 0), (3, 3, 1), (3, 3, 2), (3, 3, 3)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `itertools.product()` function for that:

```
from itertools import product

for i, x, t in product(range(4), repeat=3):
    print (i, x, t)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for i, x, t in product(range(4), repeat=3):
...     print (i, x, t)
... 
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 3)
(0, 1, 0)
# ... truncated for readability ...
(3, 2, 3)
(3, 3, 0)
(3, 3, 1)
(3, 3, 2)
(3, 3, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `itertools.product()` is a great solution, but if you should happen to want a list of lists and not tuples, you could use this:

```
[ [x,y,z] for x,y,z in itertools.product(range(4), repeat=3)]
```

or the equivalent list comprehension:

```
[ [x,y,z] for x in range(0,4)
            for y in range(0,4)
                for z in range(0,4)]
```